# why my output is coming as NaN always , i am expecting output as my series data?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying below code and getting NaN for all the columns/rows in output

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

```
data1 = np.array([1,2,4,5,6])
data2 = np.array([11,12,14,15,16])
ser1 = pd.Series(data1)
ser2 = pd.Series(data2)
ser4 = pd.Series(data1)

dataframe = pd.DataFrame([ser1,ser2,ser2],['a','b','c'])

Output is : 

    0   1   2   3   4
a   1   2   4   5   6
b   11  12  14  15  16
c   11  12  14  15  16
```

But for below code , i am getting NaN for all the data in output

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame([ser1,ser2,ser2,ser4],['a','b','c','d'],['AA','BB','CC','DD','EE'])

AA  BB  CC  DD EE
a   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
b   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
c   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
d   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

i was expecting the output should be data of series data with column name 'AA','BB','CC','DD','EE'respectively

tried to find any similar questions too on the forum but was unable to find any.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is index alignmenet, it means original columns names are from `0` to `N` created from index values of `Series`, so if define another values in list it not match and pandas return NaNs in data.

Possible solution is can create index values of each Series by your new columns names:

```
data1 = np.array([1,2,4,5,6])
data2 = np.array([11,12,14,15,16])
i = ['AA','BB','CC','DD','EE']

ser1 = pd.Series(data1, index=i)
ser2 = pd.Series(data2, index=i)
ser4 = pd.Series(data1, index=i)

dataframe = pd.DataFrame([ser1,ser2,ser2],['a','b','c'])
print (dataframe)
   AA  BB  CC  DD  EE
a   1   2   4   5   6
b  11  12  14  15  16
c  11  12  14  15  16
```

You can also specify index names in Series:

```
ser1 = pd.Series(data1, index=i, name='a')
ser2 = pd.Series(data2, index=i, name='b')
ser4 = pd.Series(data1, index=i, name='c')

dataframe = pd.DataFrame([ser1,ser2,ser2])
print (dataframe)
   AA  BB  CC  DD  EE
a   1   2   4   5   6
b  11  12  14  15  16
b  11  12  14  15  16
```

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore the index of series by stacking as an array using **[`np.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html)** , this will let you set your own index and columns:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([ser1,ser2,ser2,ser4]),['a','b','c','d'],['AA','BB','CC','DD','EE'])
```

---

```
   AA  BB  CC  DD  EE
a   1   2   4   5   6
b  11  12  14  15  16
c  11  12  14  15  16
d   1   2   4   5   6
```